# Rails 3 using scopes that returns a string value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using Rails 3.2.14 I have an Object model call `Observation` that has an attribute of `observation_status`  When I call `Observation.observation_status` it will return either `1, 2, or 3` that denotes `ready` `waiting` `finished`

I was thinking I could make a method (lets say `observation_status_words`) with conditionals that return string values, but then looked into scoping.

```
 scope :status_ready, -> { where(observation_status: '2') }
 scope :status_waiting, -> { where(observation_status: '1') }
 scope :status_finish, -> { where(observation_status: '3') }
```

But then I realized this doesn't even solve my problem.  My overall question is can I use rails 3 scopes to return string values when the statuses are different.  Otherwise, I'll resort to a class method.  I think in Rails 4 there's a pretty neat feature for this but I'm on Rails 3.2.  I'm using this as an admin panel want my users to see `ready` `waiting` `finished` instead of integers.

**UPDATE**

I resorted to doing this but people are suggesting hash mapping?

```
def observation_status_words
 case observation_status
  when 1
    return "Waiting for Reader 1"
  when 3
    return "Finished"
  else
    return "Ready"
  end
end
```

Comment: you can create a hash for the same instead of `scope`.

Comment: Um, scopes *are* class methods in disguise. In fact, ["Using a class method is the preferred way to accept arguments for scopes."](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#passing-in-arguments).

Comment: @ArupRakshit is this a feasible solution?  I didn't hash it.

Comment: @gary1410 Create a hash as `{1 => "Waiting for Reader 1", 2 => "Finished"}`, then call the hash as `hash.fetch(observation_status, 'Ready')`... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In rails 4, you have enums, and in rails 3 you can use the gem symbolize https://github.com/nofxx/symbolize.  Without using enums though, you need to have some mapping of the integer values in your DB to the corresponding strings their represent.

EDIT:

Add a hash constant like so

```
STATUS_WORD_MAPPING = {1 => :waiting, 2 => :ready, 3 => :finish}.freeze

def status_words  #Ive removed observation as it is redundant with the class name
  STATUS_WORD_MAPPING[observation_status]  # I think observation_status is a method you have defined?  either way just replace it with whatever gets you the key.
end
```

Now, for the text like `"Waiting for Ready 1"` etc.. Should either be defined in a helper as they are the correct place to have presentation logic, or perhaps use `I18n` locales.  Also, for reference, I would rename you column  `observation_status` (I think it is a column) because it's naming is redundant.  I think renaming it just `status` would be beneficial, because it looks odd seeing a method called like so `@observation.observation_status` when it could just be `@observation.status`

Comment: I ended up using this and just called `ObservationRead.observation_status_words` any objections?

Comment: I think perhaps defining a hash constant that hold the mapping would be a better idea.  I'll edit my answer to show you the idea.

Comment: I am kind of confused as to why you want a class method though. It seems like it should be an instance method.

Comment: observation_status is a column in the Observations table.  And to answer your question of class versus instance...I actually am not sure what the best practice is in this case, instance vs. class.

Comment: right, but semantically, the table's column should really just be `status` rather than `observation_status`.  It is obvious it is an attribute of observation as it is in the observation table.  To the second point, if you are looking to get the status of an instance of `Observation` then it has to be an instance method.  A class method sends a message to `Observation`, while an instance method sends an message to an object that is an instance of the class `Observation`

Answer (score 1):

That isn't what scopes are. That's totally opposite to how they're supposed to be used. Your scope is meant to be a **scope** onto which you can chain additional scopes. By returning a string, you're breaking this functionality.

Use a class method.

Comment: ah thanks, okay, I thought I was seeing some logic in some posts that allows for scopes to return string values.

Comment: @gary1410 - well they can return strings, but they shouldn't.

Comment: If you return something other than a scope from your scope, it's *by definition* not a scope. You should use a class method.